# Code keeps running without proper sequence of input

Tags: javascript, android

In the `OnClickListener`, `addFood` needs the date and time input from the datepicker fragment.

How can i make it wait till the input is done by the user?

```
Button breakfastAdd = findViewById(R.id.breakFastButton);
    breakfastAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (breakfastSearch.getCount() == 0) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast,
                        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.emptySelectionLayout));

                TextView text = layout.findViewById(R.id.toastText);
                text.setText(R.string.selectedIsEmpty);
                Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setView(layout);
                toast.show();
                Log.d("list is", "empty");

            } else {
                new datePickerFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

                addFood(context, breakfastDate, breakfastSearch, 1);
            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call your `addFood(context, breakfastDate, breakfastSearch, 1);` as an `onChange` in `datePickerFragment` instead.

Comment: would you please elaborate... i am a beginner

Comment: In the dialog popup returned in ```getSupportFragmentManager()``` you can override ```OnDateSetListener``` method to call your function when date is chosen.
In pseudocode, it should look somewhere near this: ```new datePickerFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(addFood(context, breakfastDate, breakfastSearch, 1)), "datePicker");```
and in ```getSupportFragmentManager()```:
```@Override
        public void onDateSet(View view) { //your function call }```
For a real code, I'd need to see your ```getSupportFragmentManager()```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code in you `OnClickListener` it will create `DatePickerDialog` and you will get date after you can put rest of the code:

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                int getMonth = month + 1;
                int getDay = dayOfMonth;
                String setMonth;
                String setDay;
                if (getMonth < 10)
                    setMonth = "0" + String.valueOf(getMonth);
                else
                    setMonth = String.valueOf(getMonth);

                if (getDay < 10)
                    setDay = "0" + String.valueOf(getDay);
                else
                    setDay = String.valueOf(getDay);

                String getDate = setMonth + "/" + setDay + "/" + year;
           //You have date which user picked here you can continue with rest of your code, Inflate layout etc.
            }
        }, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
        datePickerDialog.show();
```